# Can I create single file executable with nuitka?

Tags: python, windows, compilation, executable, nuitka

As title says, can I create single file executable with nuitka? I tried `--portable` and `--standalone` option but they does not seem to work. And can anyone please explain me what is the `--recurse-all` option? And if you have some other recommendations please tell me. I dont want to use pyinstaller because its too slow to start my app. Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work on my side with Qt bindings:

> Nuitka-0.5.27/bin/nuitka --standalone --recurse-all --recurse-on --recurse-directory --show-progress --show-modules --plugin-enable=qt-plugins --python-version=2.7 --remove-output --output-dir=nuitka-build main.py

You will end up with "main.dist" directory with all the dependencies and the binary "main.exe".

Comment: This results in a single directory, but not a single file.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `--onefile` option with `nuitka`?? This worked for me on linux.